# Confusions with String's split method

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I've gone through the [String's split method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) but the results are not as expected. When we split a string with the limit argument set to a negative value it always append an empty value. Why should it do that? Consider some cases

```
// Case 1
String str = "1#2#3#";
System.out.println(str.split("#").length); // Prints 3
System.out.println(str.split("#", -1).length); // Prints 4
```

What i would expect here is both prints 3.

```
// Case 2
str = "";
System.out.println(str.split("#").length); // Prints 1
System.out.println(str.split("#", -1).length); // Prints 1
```

Now since no match is found the usual split method without limit was supposed to print 0 but it creats an array with an empty string.

```
// Case 3
str = "#";
System.out.println(str.split("#").length); // Prints 0
System.out.println(str.split("#", -1).length); // Prints 2
```

Now i have a match and the split method without limit argument works fine. Its is my expected output but why wouldnt it create an empty array in this case as in case 2?

```
// Case 4
str = "###";
System.out.println(str.split("#").length); // Prints 0
System.out.println(str.split("#", -1).length); // Prints 4
```

Here first split method is as expected but why does the second one gives 4 instead of 3?

```
// Case 5
str = "1#2#3#";
System.out.println(str.split("#", 0).length); // Prints 3
System.out.println(str.split("#", 3).length); // Prints 3
System.out.println(str.split("#", 4).length); // Prints 4
```

Now the last case with positive limit. If the positive amount is <= the number of match the result is as expected. But if we give a higher positive limit it again appends an empty string to the resulting array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc for `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length**. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Emphasis mine.

In the negative limit case empty matches are not discarded so, if I represent empty with `E`:

```
1#2#3# -> 1 # 2 # 3 # E
E      -> E
#      -> E # E
###    -> E # E # E # E
```

In your last example (with a positive limit), empty trailing space is only discarded if `n == 0`.

Comment: If empty trailing are only discarded if n==0 then in case 5 when i gave n as 3 why didn't it include the empty trailing. But when i gave n as 4 it included the empty trailing.

Comment: **and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter**  You are failing to see the empty string as a string. When you put 4, it matches 3 times, then appends the empty string. When you put 3, it matches twice, then puts the rest (which happens to be another match)

Comment: @SyamS in case 5 there are **exactly 3** matches available to consume, so `0` and `3` give the same result, at 3 is the limit of the number of results. `4` matches the available `3` then appends the remaining string to the output - the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

The main source of confustion comes from the often missed section of the doc:

> ...  If n is **zero** then ..., and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

Once you get that everything makes sense.

Comment: @SyamS - That is covered elsewhere *...  If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.*

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length**. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

It appears the negative `limit` behavior is predefined as maximize matches, and store anything else at the end.

Comment: Agreed but consider case 3 the pattern can be applied 3 times and why would it add an additional empty string to make the array length 4?

Comment: there are 4 strings(all empty) in case 4. 
`(before)`#`(middle1)`#`(middle2)`#`(after)`

The array builds the 3 matches (empty string 3 times) then "Everything after the last match" (another empty string)